# Python: ValueError Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make an AI that can convert handwriting to plain text. But I'm encountering the following error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 8
  y sizes: 1
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

I have 8 images as testing dataset, each image has its own label file which looks something like this: `87 70 66 75 0 66 67 0 63 79 66 75 68 81`.

Then I combine those into 1 file (combined_labels.csv):

```
39 46 70 0 51 66 70 71 66 13,42 66 0 73 62 62 81 0 80 81 66 66 65 80,74 66 66 79 0 83 62 75 0 71 66 69 82 74 76 79,87 70 66 75 0 66 67 0 63 79 66 75 68 81,68 66 87 66 73 73 70 68 69 66 70 65 0 70 75,65 66 0 72 73 62 80 2,38 66 75 70 66 81 0 83 62 75 0 65 66,83 62 72 62 75 81 70 66 2
```

Relevant code:

```
image_paths = []
for i in range(8):
    image_paths.append("Dataset/Images/000000/000000_{}.png".format(str(i).zfill(2)))

images = []
for image_path in image_paths:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    # Resize and grayscale the image
    image = image.resize((28, 28))
    image = image.convert("L")
    images.append(np.array(image))

images = np.array(images)
images = images / 255.0
images = images.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)

...

combined_labels = pd.read_csv("combined_labels.csv", names=["labels"])

combined_labels = combined_labels["labels"].str.split(",", expand=True)

labels = combined_labels.values

labels = labels.flatten()

model.fit(images, labels, epochs=10) # Error line
```

Comment: Please remember to include the pandas and NumPy tags when asking questions about data structures they provide, as described in the Python tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags".

Comment: Full error message.  Reread what `fit` expects in its arguments!

Comment: That `#error line` comment is easy to miss.  Showing the full traceback is clearer, even if it is wordy.  In any case, you/we need to figure how your `images` and `labels` shapes are mismatched, or at least different from what `fit` expects.

Comment: I get what the error means, I just don't understand why `labels` is not of size 8. Since `combined_labels.csv` contains 8 elements.